# How to properly display tax in the checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building A Woocommerce plugin for Australia Post. Please take a look at this checkout screenshot

[image]
I added standard tax rate of 10%. And as you see in the totals, There are $4.00 as a tax. and that correct for the items of the cart. But it should calculate the 10% of the shipping cost too. The shipping rate that I received from Australia Post API is already taxed with 10% too.

So the total tax should be $5.455 not $4.00

This is how I add the shipping rate

```
          <?php 
                $this->add_rate(array(
                            'id' => 'australia_post',
                            'label' => 'Australia Post',
                            'cost' => $cost_from_api,
                            ));
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: In your plugins `calculate_shipping` method, what value is set for `calc_tax` for `$rate` variable? Also show us some code of your `calculate_shipping` method.

Comment: @Anand I updated the question, I don't set `calc_tax` because I want the tax be calculated `per_order`, not `per_item`. 
I wonder if the tax thing should be added by me or by the user himself in the Tax settings of woocommerce.

Comment: You need to add `'calc_tax' => 'per_order'` to `$this->add_rate`, that will fix the issue.